JVMをc言語で作られたアプリケーション上で動かしたいのですが、bootclasspathの設定がよくわかりません。
C言語で作られたアプリケーションの上でjava17を動かしたいと思い、
jdk-17.0.0.1をダウンロードしたあとC:\Program Files\Javaにopenjdkディレクトリを作り、
そこにjdk-17.0.0.1を配置しました。
そのあと環境変数にbinとその中のserverのpathを追加しました。
JNIを用いてJVMを起動しようと思い、以下のコードを
#define JVM_OPTION_NUM__ 4
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    JavaVMOption options[JVM_OPTION_NUM__];


options[0].optionString = "-Djava.compiler=NONE";           /* disable JIT */
options[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=."; /* user classes */
options[2].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk\jdk-17.0.0.1\lib\modules";  /* set native library path */
options[3].optionString = "-verbose:jni"; 

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;  
    vm_args.nOptions = JVM_OPTION_NUM__;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;


    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;

    jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if (res < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[debug]failed to initialize JVM\n");
        return 1;
    }

    (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
    return 0;
}

gcc -I"C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk\jdk-17.0.0.1/include" -I"C:\ProgramFiles\Java\openjdk\jdk-17.0.0.1/include/win32" java_test.c -L"C:\ProgramFiles\Java\openjdk\jdk-17.0.0.1\lib" -ljvm
でコンパイルしました。
a.exeはjvm.dllとセットでないと動かないようなのでjvm.dllをa.exeのカレントディレクトリにコピーしましたが、
"Error occurred during initialization of VM
Failed setting boot class path."
となり実行できませんでしたが、jdkのディレクトリを複製しそのserverディレクトリ上にa.exeを移動させ、実行すると正常に動作することができました。
おそらく../../libにmodulesが存在していないためであると考えています。
私の目的はこのアプリケーションをjavaをインストールしていない環境でも動かせるようにすることです。
したがって、jvm.dllが参照するmodulesの先を./lib/modulesのようにし、modulesをそこに配置して動作させたいのですがどのようにすればいいかわかりません。

環境変数が設定されていないとか、複数の版数がインストールされていて、違った版数のものが指定されているとかありませんか？ Can't load java, Failed setting boot class path after setting Environment variables, PATHの設定及び環境変数JAVA_HOMEの設定, JAVA_HOME 環境変数設定と Java 複数バージョン切り替え

java -versions
を実行すると、javaのバージョンは17が表示され、javaのディレクトリには17のjdkしかないようです。インストール済みアプリを確認してもjavaに該当する項目はありませんでした。
いずれにせよ私自身のJAVA_HOMEのmodulesではなく、アプリケーションがもつmodulesにアクセスしたいのですが../../libを参照してしまうのでexeファイルをおかなければならない位置が私の望まない位置となってしまいます。言い換えればアプリケーション動作のためのJREの同梱方法とについてお聞きしたい所存です。ご存じであればご教授いただけますでしょうか。

環境変数CLASSPATHに必要なパスを指定するか、プログラム中のoptions[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";をカレントディレクトリだけではなく必要なパスを記述してみてはどうでしょう？ Java-データベース接続 Java-MySQL接続③-1：環境変数へCLASSPATHを設定する方法 / 2017年9月, 【Java入門】classpathを指定して実行する方法(確認の方法も解説), 【Java】classpathの意味や指定方法を解説！(Windows/Mac), クラスパスの設定

jlink(および jdeps)が利用できると思います。
参考: jlink を使用した Java ランタイム | Microsoft Learn
上記リンク先の通り
jlink \
--add-modules java.base \
--strip-debug \
--no-man-pages \
--no-header-files \
--compress=2 \
--output ./javaruntime

(jdeps の結果によっては java.base 以外の指定も必要)
を実行した上で jvm.dll にパスを通して実行すれば正常に実行できるかと思います。
PATH=./javaruntime/bin/server ./a.exe


windowsユーザーなのでpath=.\bin\serverとして上記のやり方を試したところ、
jreを作成することと、dllと同じディレクトリにないexeの実行ができましたが、
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATIONのエラーが発生したため、modulesをjdkのものに置き換えたところ
無事動作することができました。おっしゃる通り、java.base以外の指定が必要であるかもしれません。
無事に解決できてよかったです。ありがとうございました。
